# Sonar 5.3 set quality profile for project via api

Tags: sonarqube

I can not deal with changes in the project properties.
I need to set default quality profile for project.

I use query:

```
curl -X POST -u 'admin:admin' -d 'resource=somedomain:aem' -d 'id=sonar.profile.java' -d 'value=java-sonar-way-aem-rules-22238' 'http://localhost:9000/sonar/api/properties'
```

It does nothing and outputs:

```
{"err_code":200,"err_msg":"property created"}
```

P.S.

somedomain:aem value I get from /api/resources > key

java-sonar-way-aem-rules-22238 value I get from /api/profiles/list?format=json > key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with Quality Profiles, so `api/qualityprofiles` to the rescue !

`api/qualityprofiles/add_project` ([documented here](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/qualityprofiles/add_project)): *Associate a project with a quality profile*

Note that your question mentions:

> default quality profile for project

There is no such thing as a *default* Quality Profile for a project. A project has one and only one Quality Profile. However a *language* can indeed have a default Quality Profile (can be set in the UI or via [api/qualityprofiles/set_default](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/qualityprofiles/set_default) ).

Comment: **api/qualityprofiles/add_project**
This is what I needed.
Thanks.